# convert slightly complex "if" statement to ternary operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have the following code from a project:

```
setTweetLibrary((curr) => {
    if (!curr[0] || (curr[0] && curr[0].id !== saved_tweets[0].id)) {
        console.log("update");
        return saved_tweets;
    } else {
        console.log("not update");
        return curr;
    }
});
```

I would like to convert this to a ternary operator with a question mark ("?") to make it neater, but I can't figure out how. Can anyone advise? Thank you!

I think I'm just really confused on how the syntax of ternary operators with multiple conditions and values

Comment: *"to make it neater"* it won't make it neater. It will make it less readable. Don't do that. Ternary are nice, but in some cases only

Comment: If you really want to stick with ternary : `return yourCondition ? console.log("update") || saved_tweets : console.log("not update") || curr;`

Comment: @Cid That last comment looks like an answer, not an attempt to clarify the question, so doesn't belong in the comment section, where it can't be accepted or voted on.

Comment: I don't want to answer this, that's ugly code. I'm just giving an hint. Many already answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ternary it would look like this:

```
setTweetLibrary((curr) => {
      return !curr[0] || (curr[0] && curr[0].id !== saved_tweets[0].id)
        ? saved_tweets
        : curr;
});
```

Note that there is no more place for console.logs. But they seem to be debug anyway.

Comment: You'd want to wrap the whole condition in `()` to avoid unwanted behavior (`return !curr[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is not a generic replacement for an if statement, only for choosing between expressions that are going to the same destination.

If we take out the logging, both branches are returning a variable:

```
if (!curr[0] || (curr[0] && curr[0].id !== saved_tweets[0].id)) {
    return saved_tweets;
} else {
    return curr;
}
```

The fact that the condition is a long expression doesn't make any difference, it's still equivalent to this:

```
if (some_condition_goes_here) {
    return saved_tweets;
} else {
    return curr;
}
```

In that case, you could use a ternary operator to select between the two - move the `return` to where the `if` is, and the `?` and `:` before the two values. Then put the whole thing in parentheses to make sure the whole thing is calculated before `return`:

```
return (
    (some_condition_goes_here)
    ? saved_tweets
    : curr
);
```

Specifically:

```
return (
    (!curr[0] || (curr[0] && curr[0].id !== saved_tweets[0].id))
    ? saved_tweets
    : curr
);
```

It might be *possible* to add the logging in there as well, but it will be much harder to read than just using a normal if statement, so if you want that - or any other logic - just stick with `if...else`.

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate this response :)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
 return (!curr[0] || (curr[0] && curr[0].id !== saved_tweets[0].id) ? saved_tweets : curr)
```